# In lua is there a way to bind an upvalue to a userdata value instead of a function?

Tags: c++, lua, metatable

In the following example a `userdata` value is created of type `MyType` and a table is created with a metafunction `__tostring` which calls `LI_MyType__tostring`. The code creates a closure-based lua OOP. My gripe with the example provided is it appears as though there is only one way to associate `userdata` with a method call, via upvalues. In and of itself, this isn't problematic unless I want to share the same metatable across instances.

In an ideal world - and what I'm hoping to unearth with this question - is there a way to associate an upvalue with a value (e.g. `userdata`) without associating it with a function call via an upvalue? I'm hoping there is a trick that will let me continue to use closure-based lua OOP *and* share the same metatable across instances. I'm not optimistic, but I figured I'd ask to see if someone has a suggestion or a non-obvious trick.

```cpp
using FuncArray = std::vector<const ::luaL_Reg>;
static const FuncArray funcs = {
  { "__tostring", LI_MyType__tostring },
};

int LC_MyType_newInstance(lua_State* L) {
  auto userdata = static_cast<MyType*>(lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(MyType)));
  new(userdata) MyType();

  // Create the metatable
  lua_createtable(L, 0, funcs.size());     // |userdata|table|
  lua_pushvalue(L, -2);                    // |userdata|table|userdata|
  luaL_setfuncs(L, funcs.data(), 1);       // |userdata|table|
  lua_setmetatable(L, -2);                 // |userdata|
  return 1;
}

int LI_MyType__tostring(lua_State* L) {
  // NOTE: Blindly assume that upvalue 1 is my userdata
  const auto n = lua_upvalueindex(1);
  lua_pushvalue(L, n);                     // |userdata|
  auto myTypeInst = static_cast<MyType*>(lua_touserdata(L, -1));
  lua_pushstring(L, myTypeInst->str());    // |userdata|string|
  return 1;                                // |userdata|string|
}
```

I'm hoping there's a way of performing something like (this is pseudo-code!):

```cpp
// Assume that arg 1 is userdata
int LI_MyType__tostring(lua_State* L) {
  const int stackPosition = -1;
  const int upvalueIndex = 1;
  const auto n = lua_get_USERDATA_upvalue(L, stackPosition, upvalueIndex);
  lua_pushvalue(L, n);                     // |userdata|
  auto myTypeInst = static_cast<MyType*>(lua_touserdata(L, -1));
  lua_pushstring(L, myTypeInst->str());    // |userdata|string|
  return 1;                                // |userdata|string|
}
```

I know this is similar to how things would be for the "normal" metatable style of OOP, but I want to keep things closure based and avoid introducing the colon syntax.

Another way of asking this question would be, is there a way to share metatables across `userdata` instances while using a closure-based OOP? Using lua's syntax from the scripting side of things, I don't think it's possible, but I'm hoping there's something that can be done on the C side of things.

---

**UPDATE** (2013-10-10): Based on [@lhf's answer to use `lua_setuservalue()` and `lua_getuservalue()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19271840/736571) the protocol I've settled on which allows me to reuse metatables is this:

1. Register a single metatable object using `luaL_newmetatable()`. This metatable can now be shared across `userdata` instances because no upvalues are used when registering the metatable.
2. Create a `userdata` value (`lua_newuserdata()`).
3. Assign the correct metatable to the `userdata` value (`lua_setmetatable()`).
4. Create and populate an instance method calls/attributes table with one upvalue, the `userdata`.
5. Use `lua_setuservalue()` on `userdata` to store a reference to the per-instance attribute/method table.
6. Change various metamethods (e.g. `__index`) to use the `userdata`'s uservalue table.

As a consequence:

- upvalues are never used in metamethods
- upvalues are only used in a value's instance methods
- there is only one extra table per instance of a given class

It's still not possible to escape creating a method/attribute table per userdata, but that overhead is nominal. It would be nice if `obj.myMethod()` would pass `obj` to `function myMethod()` somehow without using `:`, but that's exactly what `:` does because this isn't possible another way (unless you do make use of an upvalue).

Comment: I'm not following what `lua_get_USERDATA_upvalue` is suppose to do. `LI_MyType__tostring` has your udata on stack top when called, is the upvalue for that udata just referring to itself? (assuming for the moment you can associate an upvalue with udata)

Comment: Are you trying to have the following lua syntax `udata_obj.method()` act as if `udata_obj.method(udata_obj)` without using `udata_obj:method()`?

Comment: If you want all instances of `MyType` to share the same metatable, why not associate them with the same metatable on creation? You can use `luaL_newmetatable` and `luaL_getmetatable` to squirrel away the mt in the registry and retrieve it again.

Comment: @greatwolf Your second comment is correct. I want to be able to call `udata_obj.method()` without using `udata_obj:method()`. The former relies on upvalues, the latter is syntactic sugar that passes `udata_obj` as the first argument. A byproduct of `.method()` is that each instance requires its own metatable with its own closure. Is there a way on the C-side of things to get `.method()` to behave like `:method()`? I'd be nice if an upvalue could be bound to a value, not to a closure/function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`lua_setuservalue`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_setuservalue) seems to be exactly what you need. There is also of course [`lua_getuservalue`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_getuservalue).

(I'm skipping the C++ code and answering the question in the title.)

Comment: that's excellent! I'll need to think about how to use these two functions, but that appears to be exactly what I was looking for. I must have glazed over these functions when reading the 5.2 release notes. Thanks!

Comment: Added an update that explains how I've made use of this answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be trying to do it exactly, for a few reasons.

1. If you call object.method(), and you try to infer the object from the instance that was created, you're blocking your ability to pass function pointers around that behave on any object given.
2. You have cyclic references to objects that will never get garbage collected (each instance's function pointing back to the instance).

Just get the object from slot 1, and check its type matches your userdata. (luaL_checkudata)

If its not an object and tostring is called for example, just output that its a class of object name, instead of the instance details. It makes far more sense, and may well make debugging simpler if the object reports what it actually is, rather than trying to be too clever and misleading you.

Comment: 1) Lua is used to pass messages to objects. No real work is done in lua. 2) There are no cyclic references between objects, GC works as expected. `luaL_checkudata()` only works with a named metatable, but in closure example, there is no name stored in the registry that is associated with a given metatable (e.g. `tname`).

Comment: Then I would consider naming the metatables to be honest. I much prefer things to be certain in this regard. Most of the time you'd be fine, but if you started passing function pointers around, and could not be certain to which object it belongs, you're going to have a nightmare debugging it.

Comment: I used to do that, but it's easier to use Google's glog and sprinkle the relevant code paths with things like `DLOG_IF(INFO, trace_lua_calls) << "My obj in func ... " << lua_touserdata(L, n);` and match up the memory addresses.